# How can I remove a Twitter avatar and reset it to default?

Tags: twitter, avatar, profile-picture

I'd like to remove my current Twitter avatar and have it revert to one of the default avatars/profile images.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Settings` > `Profile` > `Picture` > `Delete this image.`

Comment: I found this out myself just after I posted.. Felt stupid! thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 9):

This is not possible anymore without re-uploading the original Twitter Egg image.

[image: Normal size]

[image: Default egg]

[image: Reasonably small]

Answer (score 1):

<del>From [Twitter Support](https://twitter.com/#!/Support) (DM):</del>

> <del>Alex, there is no longer an option to delete - you must upload a new photo to replace the old one.
>
>   22 Aug at 22:21</del>

**Update 02/06/2012:** This is now possible again.

[image]

And the result:

[image]